# Spring & JDBCTemplate : are resources automatically closed when using the underlying datasource?

Tags: java, spring, datasource, jdbctemplate, jooq

I'm using Spring and JDBC template to manage database access, but build the actual SQL queries using JOOQ. For instance, one DAO may look like the following:

```
public List<DrupalTaxonomyLocationTerm> getLocations(String value, String language) throws DataAccessException {

    DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource(), SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    SelectQuery q = ctx.selectQuery();
    q.addSelect(field("entity_id").as("id"),);
    q.addFrom(table("entity").as("e"));

    [...]

}
```

As you can see from the above, I'm building and executing queries using JOOQ. Does Spring still take care of closing the ResultSet I get back from JOOQ, or do I somehow "bypass" Spring when I access the data source directly and pass the data source on to JOOQ?

Comment: When you directly work with the `DataSource` spring isn't going to do anything for you. Maybe JOOQ is doing something for you but definitely spring isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring doesn't do anything with the objects generated from your `DataSource`, i.e. `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet`. From a Spring (or generally from a  `DataSource` perspective), you have to do that yourself.

However, jOOQ will always:

- close `Connection` objects obtained from a `DataSource`. This is documented in jOOQ's [`DataSourceConnectionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DataSourceConnectionProvider.html)
- close `PreparedStatement` objects right after executing them - unless you explicitly tell jOOQ to keep an open reference through [`Query.keepStatement()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#keepStatement-boolean-)
- close `ResultSet` objects right after consuming them through any [`ResultQuery.fetchXXX()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetch--) method - unless you explicitly want to keep an open [`Cursor`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html) with [`ResultQuery.fetchLazy()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchLazy--)

By design, jOOQ inverses JDBC's default behaviour of keeping all resources open and having users tediously close them explicitly. jOOQ closes all resources eagerly (which is what people do 95% of the time) and allows you to explicitly keep resources open where this is useful for performance reasons.

[See this page of the jOOQ manual for differences between jOOQ and JDBC](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/comparison-with-jdbc/).